# Reference for introduction to algebraic linkage theory

Tags: ring-theory, reference-request, commutative-algebra

1- Are there books or lecture notes (including videos) that comprehensively introduce the algebraic theory of linkages, as well as important results and their proofs?

2- Is there an english context for the paper:
*C. Peskine, L. Szpiro, Liaison des variétés algebriques, Invent. Math. 26 (1974) 271-302.*

I have read Atiah-macdonald's book and 3 chapters of Bruns-Herzog, but I'm *not* familiar with algebraic geometery.

thank you.

Comment: There's some stuff in the last chapter of Eisenbud. I don't know if that would be sufficient for your purposes.

Comment: thank you. i've read it. it was helpful, (although i could not understand all of it). but i need more.